# Conditional expectation of random variables

Tags: random-variable, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, conditional-expectation

A fair die is rolled till $1$ is observed. Let $X$ be the number of rolls and $Y$ be the number of $6$ obtained in these $X$ rolls. Find (a) $E[Y|X=x]$, (b) $E[Y]$.

My Solution:

Once we are given that $X=x$ then we know that the 1st $1$ was obtained in the $x^{th}$ roll and in the first $x-1$ rolls $1$ never appeared and so $Y|X=x$ follows a Binomial $(x-1, 1/5)$ distribution and so $E[Y|X=x]=\frac{x-1}{5}$. Now by Tower property we have $$E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]=E[\frac{X-1}{5}]=\frac{E[X]-1}{5}=\frac{6-1}{5}=1$$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{x-1}{5}$ and $1$ look reasonable.  There are other ways of getting the same results, but yours is as good as any.

Comment: Answering this requires no calculation and almost no knowledge of distributions.  Because the five values 2 through 6 are equivalent in this setting, it's immediate that $E[Y\mid X=x]$ is one-fifth of the number of rolls preceding observing $1$ and that $E[Y]$ is one-fifth $E[X]-1.$

Answer (score 1):

$E[X] = 6$ because in a very long series of rolls arbitrarily close to $1/6$ of all outcomes will be $1,$ whence the mean waiting time to observe a $1$ will be arbitrarily close to $1/(1/6)=6.$

Because the remaining outcomes $2,3,4,5,6$ all play equivalent roles in this problem, if we let $Y_k$ be the number of times a $k$ is observed,

$$E[Y_k\mid X = x] = E[Y_6\mid X = x] = E[Y\mid X=x].$$

But *every one* of the first $x-1$ rolls results in $k\in \{2,3,4,5,6\},$ showing  $$X = 1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5 + Y_6,$$ whence by linearity of conditional expectation (and taking out what is known),

$$x = E[X\mid X=x] = E[1\mid X=x] + E[Y_2\mid X = x] + \cdots + E[Y_6\mid X = x].$$

Therefore each of these five equal conditional expectations is one-fifth of their total,

$$E[Y\mid X = x] = E[Y_k\mid X = x] = \frac{x-1}{5}.$$

In the same fashion, linearity of (unconditional) expectation asserts

$$6 = E[X] = 1 + E[Y_2] + \cdots + E[Y_6] = 1 + 5E[Y],$$

giving

$$E[Y] = \frac{6-1}{5} = 1.$$

Comment: Smart argument without explicitly finding the distribution first (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is correct (+1).  The step of deriving the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X = x$ may be made a little more formal as follows: for $x \geq 2$ and $0 \leq y < x$,
\begin{align}
 & P(Y = y|X = x) = \frac{P(Y = y, X = x)}{P(X = x)}
=\frac{\binom{x - 1}{y} \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{x - 1 - y}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^y\frac{1}{6}}{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x - 1}\frac{1}{6}} \\
=& \binom{x - 1}{y} \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{x - 1 - y}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^y.
\end{align}

Hence $Y | X = x \sim B(x - 1, 1/5)$ (technically this relation only holds for $x \geq 2$. If $x = 1$, then $Y$ is trivially degenerated at $0$). The numerator in the penultimate expression calculates, in a sequence of $x$ independent Beroulli trials, the probability of observing "6" for $y$ times in the first $x - 1$ trials, observing "1" in the $x$-th trial for the first time.